# pipenv is installed, but $ pipenv --version shows as command not found

Tags: python, pipenv

Newbie here not understanding how pipenv can simultaneously show as installed and not installed at the same time. Am using Windows 10 (2004) in the VS Code terminal:

`$ pip install pipenv` returns this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\billa\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2018.11.26)
    Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\billa\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\billa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (2019.6.16)
    Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\billa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (16.7.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\users\billa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (44.0.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in c:\users\billa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.1.1)
```

But:

`$ pipenv --version`

Returns this:

`$ pipenv: command not found`

Perplexingly, if I use Ubuntu in Windows terminal, it reports back properly:
`$ pipenv, version 2020.6.2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added environment path in windows?

Comment: Yes, but upon review, I see now that I didn't do it correctly. Problem solved, thank-you Abhik.